# C#: What happens when assigning auto-property?

Tags: c#, properties

I learned that in C# there is this thing called autoproperty, which ist normally automatically generated by the compiler if i declared a variable like:
public List myList { get; set; }

```
public class MyClass
{

   private List<int> myList;
   public List<int> MyList
   {
       get
       {
           return this.myList;
       }
       set
       {
           this.myList = value;
       }
   }
}
```

It lets me access the variable like:

```
   List<int> a = myInstance.MyList;
```

So it works like a function, but is called like a normal object.
But what is really assigned on a ? Is there assigned a "deep link" on the object myList or is there assigned something like a "functor" on the get function?
What i mean is, if i work with a, will the get function be called again everytime?

The reason why I'm asking: If I'm using this in a multithreaded case with some locking of the object in the get and set function I don't want to bypass the locking. So if I first assign myList on a and then work with it, it won't be locked anymore? Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

> But what is really assigned on `a`?

The type of `a` is `List<int>`, and lists are reference types, so the variable contains a reference to a list. **C# doesn't lie to you. The type of the variable is the type of the variable**.

> it works like a function, but is called like a normal object.

This sentence makes no sense and it indicates to me that you have some misunderstanding of how C# works.  "Objects" are not things that are "called" unless they are delegates. It sounds like you are confusing properties, variables, objects and delegates.  **Learn what those things are**. It will be difficult to be successful in C# programming if you do not know the correct names of all the parts.

I think what you intended to say is that *a property is a member which is accessed like a field, but reads and writes of the property are implemented as calls to member access methods*.

> What i mean is, if i work with `a`, will the get function be called again everytime?

You could answer this question for yourself by trying it:

```
myInstance.MyList = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30 };
List<int> a = myInstance.MyList;
myInstance.MyList = new List<int> { 100, 200, 300 };
Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
```

If `a` fetches the property again, it should be 100.  If it does not, it should be 10.  Make a prediction about what will happen, and then try it and see if you were right.

> If I'm using this in a multithreaded case with some locking of the object in the get and set function I don't want to bypass the locking. So if I first assign `MyList` to `a` and then work with it, it won't be locked anymore? Am I right?

Yes. I will take this opportunity to point out that **it is an extremely poor programming practice to make a public interface that exposes an object that must be locked**. Better options are:

- Do not write multithreaded programs. It's really hard to get them right.
- If you must, do not write multithreaded programs that share memory across threads.
- If you must share memory, **use threadsafe collections, always**.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are just better named `List<int> getValue()` and `setValue(List<int> value)` function pair. There are some minor properties:

- they appear on reflection
- they can be declared in interfaces/abstract classes
- they are used like a field, except in rare cases (out and ref parameters)

But overall that is all there is to them.

Autoimplement proeprties are the same as manual ones, except the backing field has no name (you could use in your code), so there is 0 chance to accidentally access the backingfield.

One of **the** most important rules with Properties is to not write the Backing fields, especially in class code. And just lower casing it does not work. I lost track how often I coded so fast, a Upper case did not stick. For reliable naming, append a underscore to the backing field. `_MyList` and `MyList` are pretty hard to mix up. `MyList` and `myList` are easy to mix up.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `myInstance.MyList` to `a`, you call the `MyList` get Property which copies the reference `myList` into `a`. If you then work with `a` you will be working directly with the List referred to by the private `myList`. You will *only* go via the get Property if you actually call it.

This is basically losing the private nature of `myList`. If you want to force the caller to go via functions which do things like locking then you will have to write functions for the operations you want to allow, like adding to the List, without exposing the actual List to the caller.

There's no need to do this in C# for thread safe operations - you should use the [Concurrent Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.7.2) which implement these operations for free.

Comment: No, absolutely it does not put a *reference to the field into the variable*. It puts the *value* of the field into the variable, and *that value is a reference*! It is very, very important that you understand the difference. **Almost nothing in this answer's first paragraph is correct**.

Comment: We *can* get a reference to a field in C# 7:  `class C { private int f; public ref int M() => ref this.f;}` and now we have a *reference to a field*.  But that is *very different* than the *contents of a field of reference type*.

Comment: Thanks Eric Lippert for pointing out my incorrect language, I have edited to correct that. I do understand the difference, just poorly explained it.